# Git branching strategy when working in development teams

Tags: git, branch

What is the best Git Strategy when having a main branch where all sub branches are dependent on each other. So for instance I first create the main branch called classroom. Then I create a sub branch called classroom-models. Once this is finished I create a branch called classroom-services. The classroom-services branch is dependent on the classes that are created in the classroom-models branch.

We use Pull Requests in order to review the code. But sometimes the Pull Requests aren't done when you want to start on the second branch. I would tend to branch of of the main branch and merge the first branch. When the first branch is reviewed and merged into the main branch. I would again merge all possible changes into the second branch.

Another problem is when the first and second branch are ready and a Pull Request is created. Then the changed in the Pull Request for the second branch also contain the changes in the first branch.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I prefer to do next:

1. make second branch on first branch HEAD
2. if first branch changed (due to review issues) - create new 'second-2' branch and cherry-pick commits unique to 'second' branch.
3. do not create pull-request until first branch merged
4. after frist branch merged - create new 'second-3' branch from 'main' and cherry-pick commits unique to 'second' branch
5. create pull request for 'second-N' branch and proceeed with it

I prefer rebase(cherry-picks) because it keep history more clean and understendable.